# window.opener.location.href history not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser-history, back

I am opening a window by using window.open and in that window there are certain links upon clicking on the links it redirects the original page to the link clicked and the closes the new window.

```
$('a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var get_href=$(this).attr('href');

  window.opener.location.href=get_href;
  window.close();
});
```

Now the redirect take us to the booking page when I click on the back button in chrome it take it back to the account page but when I tried it on the firefox it redirects the page to the login page instead it should redirect to the account page.if we can reload the page that will do as well.

I Have tried

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){window.location.reload();}
```

and this in the php header

```
// any valid date in the past
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
// always modified right now
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
// HTTP/1.1 
header("Cache-Control: private, no-store, max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-          check=0, pre-check=0");
// HTTP/1.0
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

But None of is working the below code is working it is throwing an alert but does not reload

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
  return confirmationMessage;                            //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.onbeforeunload = function(){window.location.reload();}` will never work. That is a denial of service attack

**ASSUMING** pages from same origin, you can try this

1. in parent:

`window.name="parentWindow"`

2. In child

`<a href="page.html" target="parentWindow">Open page in parent</a>`

Comment: I tried that but its not working mind you I am using an iframe so the url in the browser remains the same only the iframe url changes

Comment: Where are you using an iframe? A page in an iFrame has a top or parent, not an opener
If the link is in an iFrame then the named targetwindow should still work